# Is there a faster way to create a matrix of indices from ragged data?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have data that is given as a list of ordered pairs mixed with scalars. The pairs can contain infinite bounds. My goal is to convert the data into an index used in future computations.

```
data = {{1, ∞}, {-∞, 2}, 3, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};
```

This gives me all of the unique values present in `data`.

```
udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@data], Less]

==> {-∞, 1, 2, 3, ∞}
```

Now I use `Dispatch` to create replacement rules based on the unique values.

```
dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]];
```

Finally I replace the values with their indices and expand scalars `a` such that they are also pairs `{a,a}`. This results in a matrix of indices which is what I'm after.

```
Replace[data /. dsptch, a_Integer :> {a, a}, 1]

==> {{2, 5}, {1, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}
```

NOTES:

1. The number of unique values is generally small compared to the length of `data` but this doesn't have to be the case.
2. Any real numbers are possible. The `data` I've shown simply gives a sense of the structural possibilities.

**Question:
Is there a way to create the final matrix of indices that is much faster than what I'm doing here?**

**Edit:** To test the how potential solutions scale I recommend using the following data.  It is fairly representative of a true-to-life case.

```
inf = {#, ∞} & /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], 3*10^5];
neginf = {-∞, #} & /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], 10^5];
int = Sort /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], {10^5, 2}];
num = RandomChoice[Range[1000], 5*10^5];

testData = RandomSample[Join[inf, neginf, int, num]];
```

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle. It seems that `Sort@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten` is practically unbeatable. I tried.

Comment: @rcollyer I'm just hoping its interesting enough that someone can trounce my current approach. The biggest bottleneck the heavy use of replacements but I'm at a loss for finding a novel approach.

Comment: Realizing that overcoming `Sort...Flatten` was going to be next to impossible, I tried using `Reap` and `Sow` to simultaneously collect the unique terms and substitute in a function that would later return the index. Twice as slow as your method. Tried using an implementation of a binary tree, it can't handle $10^6$ terms, e.g. $10^5$ terms on par with your implementation running $10^6$ terms. So, I don't know exactly optimize the bottleneck any further.

Comment: It's not fast, but it might give you a different approach to tweak `If[Length[#] == {}, {#, #}, #] & /@ ArrayComponents[testData];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A modest improvement when you replace `Replace[...]` with `Transpose@Thread`:

```
 (udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@testData], Less]; 
 dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]]; 
 out1 = Replace[testData /. dsptch, a_Integer :> {a, a}, 1];) // AbsoluteTiming 
 (* {2.1282128, Null} *)

 (udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@testData], Less]; 
 dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]]; 
 out2 = Transpose@Thread[testData /. dsptch];) // AbsoluteTiming 
 (* {1.9421942, Null} *)
 out1==out2
 (* True  *)
```

Comment: That `Thread` trick for converting the numbers to pairs is very useful +1.

Comment: @AndyRoss I have to agree with you on that. Definitely interesting and useful.

Answer (score 7):

I get about a 20% speed up by using kguler's `Thread` trick to transform the data at the beginning, saving the `Transpose` until the end. There seems to be a slight advantage to working on data with dimensions {2,10^6} over data with dimensions {10^6,2}. I'm not sure why.

```
twobiglists=Thread[testData];
udata=Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@twobiglists],Less];
dsptch=Dispatch[Thread[udata->Range[Length[udata]]]];
result=Transpose[twobiglists/.dsptch];
```

Comment: The `Thread` approach has the advantage of not doing the double replace at the end. So, that likely gives some of the speed up.

Comment: @rcollyer - I agree, `Thread` seems to be more efficient than `a_:>{a,a}` but also `Flatten` is about 3 times faster on the transformed data.

Comment: Likely that's due to the simpler structure, i.e. `{{..}, {..}}` would be easier to `Flatten` then `{(_ |{_,_})..}`.

Answer (score 6):

This is a little faster approach:

first,transform `data` and `udata` a little, represent Infinity and -Infinity by "a1" and "a0" :

```
 data2 = Block [{DirectedInfinity = "a" <> ToString[# + 1] &}, data]
 =>{{1, "a2"}, {"a0", 2}, 3, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}
 udata2 = Block [{DirectedInfinity = "a" <> ToString[# + 1] &}, udata]
 =>{"a0", 1, 2, 3, "a2"}
```

second, rebuild dispatch table:

```
dsptch2 = Dispatch[Thread[udata2 -> Range[Length[udata2]]]];
```

third, `Replace` and `Replace`:

```
Replace[Replace[data2, dsptch2, {-1}], a_Integer :> {a, a}, 1]
==>{{2, 5}, {1, 3}, {4, 4}, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}
```

the main difference is the inner `Replace`, make some bigger test data:

```
l = Join[Range[ 100], {\[Infinity] , -\[Infinity] }];
l2 = Partition [RandomChoice[l, 10^6], 2];
data = Riffle[l2, Join[{\[Infinity] , -\[Infinity] }, Range[ 100]], 5];
```

now timing the inner `Replace` part alone:

```
c1 = data2 /. dsptch2; // Timing (*original approach*)
c2 = Replace[data2, dsptch2, {-1}]; // Timing (*modified approach*)
c1 == c2

=>{0.749, Null}
=>{0.343, Null}
=>True
```

we see the speed is doubled, now timing the whole:

```
(udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@data], Less];
  dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]];
  a1 = Replace[data /. dsptch, a_Integer :> {a, a}, 1];) // Timing 

(data2 = Block [{DirectedInfinity = "a" <> ToString[# + 1] &}, data];
  udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@data], Less];
  udata2 = 
   Block [{DirectedInfinity = "a" <> ToString[# + 1] &}, udata];
  dsptch2 = Dispatch[Thread[udata2 -> Range[Length[udata2]]]];
  a4 = Replace[Replace[data2, dsptch2, {-1}], a_Integer :> {a, a}, 
    1];) // Timing 
a4 == a1

=>{1.092, Null}
=>{0.889, Null}
=>True
```

a little faster...

Comment: This approach seemed promising until I tried it with more representative data. `data = RandomChoice[data, 10^6]` where `data` is the original list I provided.

Comment: Note that I've updated my post to include some good test data that is more true-to-life.

Answer (score 3):

*Now incorporating Simon Woods's improvement and including his code in the timings.*

Pardon the very late answer but hopefully it is useful to someone with a similar problem.

- Since the depth of the data is known it is faster to use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) rather than [`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)
- Using an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html)<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55980/121)</sup> in place of the [`Dispatch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html) table is faster still

Test data:

```
SeedRandom[0]

inf = {#, ∞} & /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], 3*10^5];
neginf = {-∞, #} & /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], 10^5];
int = Sort /@ RandomChoice[Range[1000], {10^5, 2}];
num = RandomChoice[Range[1000], 5*10^5];

testData = RandomSample[Join[inf, neginf, int, num]];
```

Data and time common to each method:

```
udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@testData], Less]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.247, Null}
> ```

Relative performance:

```
(* kglr *)    
(dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]];
  r0 = Transpose @ Thread[testData /. dsptch];) // RepeatedTiming

(* Simon Woods *)
(dsptch = Dispatch[Thread[udata -> Range[Length[udata]]]];
  r1 = Transpose[Thread @ testData /. dsptch];) // RepeatedTiming

(* Replace *)
(dsptch = Dispatch@Thread[udata -> Range@Length@udata];
  r2 = Replace[Thread @ testData, dsptch, {2}]\[Transpose];) // RepeatedTiming

(* Association, for v10+ *)
(asc = AssociationThread[udata -> Range@Length@udata];
  r3 = (Lookup[asc, #] & /@ Thread @ testData)\[Transpose];) // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.673, Null}
>
> {0.573, Null}
>
> {0.446, Null}
>
> {0.390, Null}
> ```

```
r0 === r1 === r2 === r3
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `PositionIndex` (new in 10.0) and `SequenceReplace` (new in 
11.3)

```
data = {{1, \[Infinity]}, {-\[Infinity], 2}, 3, {2, 2}, {2, 3}};

udata = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[Flatten @ data], Less];

SequenceReplace[{a_Integer} :> {a, a}][data /. First /@ PositionIndex @ udata]
```

{{2, 5}, {1, 3}, 4, {3, 3}, {3, 4}}