# Using Memoization with a Mutable Object

Tags: data-structures, memoization

In looking for a solution to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4571/52), I ran across some old binary tree code by [Daniel Lichtblau](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/lichtblau/Links/index_lnk_8.html), reproduced below:

```
Clear[leftsubtree, rightsubtree, nodevalue, emptyTree, treeInsert]
leftsubtree[{left_, _, _}] := left
rightsubtree[{_, _, right_}] := right
nodevalue[{_, val_, _}] := val
emptyTree = {};

treeInsert[emptyTree, elem_] := {emptyTree, elem, emptyTree}
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; SameQ[nodevalue[tree], elem] := tree
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; OrderedQ[{nodevalue[tree], elem}] :=
 {leftsubtree[tree], 
  nodevalue[tree], treeInsert[rightsubtree[tree], elem]}
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] := {treeInsert[leftsubtree[tree], elem], 
  nodevalue[tree], rightsubtree[tree]}
```

When mapped onto a list, `treeInsert` gives you a sorted duplicate free list. For example,

```
tr = {};
Scan[(tr = treeInsert[tr, #]) &, RandomInteger[100, 5]];
Flatten@tr 
(* {13, 28, 53, 59, 88} *)
```

On my machine, this takes ~2 s to process `RandomInteger[10, 10^5]`, but this increases to nearly 20 s with `RandomInteger[10, 10^6]`.  There are likely other techniques to speed this up, but I am curious as to how memoization could be adapted to this problem. At issue, though, is that the `tree` changes with each insertion, and so it cannot be used directly for memoization because the definition depends directly on that form. How would one do this?

**Edit**: as I discovered in my own testing, `Fold` works much better than `Scan` for creating a tree, as follows

```
tr = Fold[treeInsert, {}, RandomInteger[100, 5]];
Flatten@tr 
(* {13, 28, 53, 59, 88} *)
```

**Update**: while my question, per se, was not answered directly, the answers themselves indicated that there were better ways to accomplish what I wanted. In the end, I chose the one I did for two reasons: speed and simplicity.

Comment: I think the Scan[(tr= part of the post did not make it onto the page.

Comment: @ruebenko no it didn't. Posted it before I finished the thought, apparently. It's fixed, now.

Comment: This does not use memoization, but have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246330/delete-repeating-list-elements-preserving-order-of-appearance/5251034#5251034)? It is quite fast (being compiled), and along the same lines as what you discuss.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I did see that answer, and I like it a lot. Unfortunately, $\pm\infty$ is not a real number, so it would have to be dealt with separately. However, I was thinking along those lines when it occurred to me that I did not know of a way to adapt memoization to this particular solution.

Comment: @rcollyer I see. But if the problem is only about infinities, then, since the resulting list will be sorted, they can only be the first and last elements of the resulting list, if present. What I usually do is to replace them temporarily with `Min[list]-1` and `Max[list]+1`, then use `Compile`, then replace back. This way, you can keep it almost as fast as without infinities.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin well, I was going to overload the function with `treeInsert[tree_, DirectedInfinity[d_]]` and set a flag that can be handled later. It would still involve processing the elements one at a time, as opposed to within a compiled for loop, and would likely have to involve ``Internal`Bag`` instead of a `List`.

Comment: @rcollyer Ok, I see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For such small trees I would memoize those that already have the element...

```
ClearAll[leftsubtree, rightsubtree, nodevalue, emptyTree, treeInsert]
leftsubtree[{left_, _, _}] := left
rightsubtree[{_, _, right_}] := right
nodevalue[{_, val_, _}] := val
emptyTree = {};

treeInsert[emptyTree, elem_] := {emptyTree, elem, emptyTree}

(*This is the changed line*)
t : treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; ! FreeQ[tree, elem] := t = tree

treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; 
  OrderedQ[{nodevalue[tree], elem}] := {leftsubtree[tree], 
  nodevalue[tree], treeInsert[rightsubtree[tree], elem]}
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] := {treeInsert[leftsubtree[tree], elem], 
  nodevalue[tree], rightsubtree[tree]}
```

Comment: This gives a 60% increase in speed over Pillsy' s similar [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4656/52) on my machine. Likely because it is the common pattern, and hence higher on the list. +1

Comment: As a side note, for testing they're small trees, but that is not guaranteed to always be the case. Although with Andy's test data, you don't expect the number of unique elements to exceed 1000, so I guess small still applies.

Comment: With further investigation, this solution seems to win big over mine when you miss the cache a lot.

Comment: As I noted in the update, I am selecting yours for speed and simplicity.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the simplest approach I came up with is to just memoize the result *after* you generate it.

```
ClearAll[leftSubTree, rightSubTree, nodeValue, emptyTree, treeInsert];

leftSubTree[{left_, _, _}] := left;
rightSubTree[{_, _, right_}] := right;
nodeValue[{_, val_, _}] := val;
emptyTree = {};

treeInsert[emptyTree, elem_] := {emptyTree, elem, emptyTree};
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; SameQ[nodeValue@tree, elem] := tree;
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; OrderedQ[{nodeValue[tree], elem}] :=
  With[{inserted =
     {leftSubTree[tree], nodeValue[tree], 
      treeInsert[rightSubTree[tree], elem]}},
   treeInsert[inserted, elem] = inserted];
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] :=
  With[{inserted =
     {treeInsert[leftSubTree[tree], elem], nodeValue[tree], 
      rightSubTree[tree]}},
   treeInsert[inserted, elem] = inserted];
```

The way this works means that if you ever try to insert an element into a tree that already contains it, it will return the memoized result immediately, and it will also return the memoized result if you've ever inserted that element into another tree identical to the one you're using now. This lead to a factor of 10 speedup on my machine with that million element list.

It has the advantage of not only working well more with than one tree: it actually will be faster if those trees share structure!

Comment: +1, that's an interesting idea I hadn't considered.

Comment: As an interesting side note, repeated applications on the same data set do not give any additional speed-up. Likely, that is the cost of traversing the tree itself. Also, for Andy's question, though, `OrderedQ` puts $\pm\infty$ at the end, so to use it with those values, `Less` is better, but not any faster. :P

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach that inserts only if an element is not yet in the tree:

```
ClearAll[leftsubtree, rightsubtree, nodevalue, emptyTree, treeInsert, \
inTreeQ]
leftsubtree[{left_, _, _}] := left
rightsubtree[{_, _, right_}] := right
nodevalue[{_, val_, _}] := val
inTreeQ[_] = False;
emptyTree = {};

treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; inTreeQ[elem] := tree    
treeInsert[emptyTree, 
  elem_] := (inTreeQ[elem] = True; {emptyTree, elem, emptyTree})
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; SameQ[nodevalue[tree], elem] := tree
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; ! inTreeQ[elem] && 
   OrderedQ[{nodevalue[tree], elem}] := {leftsubtree[tree], 
  nodevalue[tree], treeInsert[rightsubtree[tree], elem]}
treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; ! inTreeQ[elem] := {treeInsert[
   leftsubtree[tree], elem], nodevalue[tree], rightsubtree[tree]}


tr = {};
AbsoluteTiming[
 Scan[(tr = treeInsert[tr, #]) &, RandomInteger[10, 10^6]];]
Flatten@tr
```

This works well when there are a few different elements like in `RandomInteger[10,...]` Have a look and see if this works for you.

**Edit**: I made another improvement by moving the most common case `treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; inTreeQ[elem] := tree` (that the element is in the tree) up the chain

Comment: It definitely speeds things up (by a very large margin), but what if I need two, or more, trees?

Comment: hm, how about using an index for each tree, like in `inTreeQ[1,_]=False` you'd then have to give an index to each tree ) or you could use an Unique["tr"] symbol.

Comment: The index idea is a good one. How about you make a custom "object": `Tree[index, treedata]`. Then, have a form of that only accepts an element, `treeInsert[elem_]`, which will "create" the `Tree` and give it the unique index when used. Then unique trees can be had by all ... :)