# How does a construct like `i : func[arg_] := i = an expression using arg` work?

Tags: programming, function-construction, pattern-matching

Occasionally I run into a `Pattern` that looks like `i:func[arg_]:=i= an expression using arg`

I have two questions on this:

1. Can someone explain what this `Pattern` does? I do not understand the purpose of (if that is what is happening!) the subsequent application of setting the `Pattern` *i* as the `Function` *func* which then "redefines" *i* via `SetDelayed` and then some memoization (?) seems to be applied to *i* via `Set`.
2. How could I have found this out myself? I could not get a clear understanding from `Trace` or inspecting `func//DownValues` neither did I find it in the `Pattern[]` entry in the documentation or `Pattern` related tutorials.

An example is given in [peg solitaire](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6704/performance-tuning-for-game-solving-peg-solitaire-senku). The `Pattern` used is:

```
i:findMoves[tab_]:=i=Flatten[#, 1]&[findMovesZero[tab, #]&/@Position[tab, 0]]
```

Another - more compact - one in an answer on: [Using Memoization with a Mutable Object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4658/14625).

```
t : treeInsert[tree_, elem_] /; ! FreeQ[tree, elem] := t = tree
```

Comment: In a notebook type and select `:`, then press **F1** (or whatever the help key is on your system). This shows in the documentation that `s : obj` represents the pattern `obj` with the name `s` assigned to it.

Comment: @Jack LaVigne , Yes, I understand how to use the help system and I know `:` represents a `Pattern` (I actually refer to it in my question). However this seems more complicated as here the pattern is the `Function` func which subsequently again "defines" `i` via `SetDelayed` and then some memoization is applied to it via `Set`. At least that's what I see, which I doubt I understand correctly.

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne thanks for your comment; I edited the question to highlight what I am missing..

Comment: `name:function[arg_]:=name=(do something with arg)` is the same effect as `function[arg_]:=function[arg]=(do something with arg)` - it accomplishes "memoization" by dynamically defining a pattern with the computed result. The effect is documented in the tutorial "functions that remember their results" (or something like that), I don't recall if they show/use the first form there.

Comment: @Sander: Feel free to self-answer, often done here. A little explanation re: your "Ah-Ha!" could help others.

Comment: This is close to being a duplicate of [(2676)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2676/121) as I described and recommended this specific syntax.  Sander, do you feel it would be appropriate to close (but *not* delete) this Question as a duplicate of that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I personally do not mind as I understand it now. However, I was aware of the memoization construct you described in your referred post and yet needed ciao to help me recognise "my" construct is (indeed) equivalent. I cannot comment on the value (if any) it may bring to others being equally puzzled.

Comment: Okay.  Had you read my **A note regarding syntax** section (with `mem :`) and it was still not clear?  If so I should rewrite that section for improved clarity.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I missed it! Okay to close this one as duplicate. Only thing I can suggest is that it is a bit at the end for what I think is a very valuable alternative.

Comment: I somewhat rewrote that section of my answer and hopefully it is now at least a little bit more clear.  I also added a direct link from that section to your Q&A.  This "duplicate" shall remain both to expand the subject and to provide an entry point to the larger Q&A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a form of memoization by dynamically defining a `Pattern` with the results of the executed `Expression` as clarified by @ciao.

The standard form is documented in [Functions that remember values they have found](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) and looks like:

```
f[x_]:=f[x]=rhs
```

So as an example:

```
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]
```

behaves the same as

```
i:f[x_] := i =  f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]
```

**To demonstrate, this example comes from the referred documentation:**

```
Clear[f];
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]
?f
```

> f[x_]:=f[x]=f[x-1]+f[x-2]

```
DownValues@f
```

> {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2])}

```
f[0] = f[1] = 1;
?f
DownValues@f
```

> f[0]=1
>
> f[[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)]=1
>
> f[x_]:=f[x]=f[x-1]+f[x-2]
>
> {HoldPattern[f[0]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)] :> 1, 
>    HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2])}

```
f[5];
?f
DownValues@f
```

> f[0]=1
>
> f[[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)]=1
>
> f[2]=2
>
> f[3]=3
>
> f[4]=5
>
> f[5]=8
>
> f[x_]:=f[x]=f[x-1]+f[x-2]
>
> {HoldPattern[f[0]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 2, 
>    HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 3, HoldPattern[f[4]] :> 5, HoldPattern[f[5]] :> 8, 
>    HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> (f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2])}

**The following is the equivalent in the alternative form:**

```
Clear[f]
i : f[x_] := i = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]
DownValues@f
```

> {HoldPattern[i : f[x_]] :> (i = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2])}

```
f[0] = f[1] = 1;
f[5];
?f
DownValues@f
```

> f[0]=1
>
> f[[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)]=1
>
> f[2]=2
>
> f[3]=3
>
> f[4]=5
>
> f[5]=8
>
> i:f[x_]:=i=f[x-1]+f[x-2]
>
> {HoldPattern[f[0]] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[1](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html)] :> 1, HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 2, 
>    HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 3, HoldPattern[f[4]] :> 5, HoldPattern[f[5]] :> 8, 
>    HoldPattern[i : f[x_]] :> (i = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2])}

Comment: Very nicely answered! +1

Comment: @ciao Thanks, could not have done it without you :)