# Interlacing a single number into a long list

Tags: list-manipulation

This seems like it should be a simple question, but I am running into some difficulty in doing this with *Mathematica*. Right now, I have a list like this:

```
data1={0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 10, 3, 11, 1, 0, 0, 32, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2, 0, 25, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
       0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 95, 4, 16, 11, 2, 0, 0, 
       81, 35, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 42, 0, 0, 0};
```

I want to insert "1997" into the list after each element and transpose it, so that it will look like so: `{{1997,0},{1997,0},{1997,0}...}`. So far so good.

Unfortunately, the only way I know how to do this is to manually create a list of equal length to `data1` (70 "1997"s in a row). I also do not know how to create a list that is just 70 "1997"s in a row. I've plumbed the documentation and tried every command I can think of, but the closest I can get are either functions or a list that resembles `{{1997,0,1997,0,1997,0...}` etc.

Comment: Ian, you have great talent for asking questions that have a thousand and one ways to do them.

Comment: There are several good solutions to your problem below, but as an aside about your question of how to generate a list, there are a couple of easy ways: `ConstantArray[1997,70]` or `Table[1997,{70}]`.

Comment: @wxffles Thanks for this. It's too bad `ConstantArray` isn't in the "list manipulations" docs section, as it's a great command to have in one's list toolkit!

Comment: @rcollyer Indeed - making it so tricky to pick just one as the accepted answer...

Comment: Consider speed as the final arbiter. Most likely, then, it is `Thread`.

Comment: It seems I've found a pretty fast and simple method based on `Tuples`. This question is really good example for testing efficiency of various methods.

Comment: Ian, I find `ConstantArray` to verbose, for my tastes, though, I do use it. If I want something terse, I use `Array[1997&, 70]`. I doubt it is faster to execute, but it is a lot faster to type! However, ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[Array[...]] == False``, while it is `True` for `ConstantArray`, implying a speed hit for `Array`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
Thread[{1997,data1}]
```

Answer (score 32):

Absolutely unbeatable :

```
Tuples[{{1997}, data1}]
```

All other methods are much slower even Verbeia's `{1997,#}&/@ data1` or dws' `Thread[{1997, data1}]`

```
Tuples[{{1997}, data1}] === ({1997, #} & /@ data1) ===  Thread[{1997, data1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We compare the most efficient methods for a long list :

```
 list = RandomChoice[data1, 10^7];
```

and results :

```
Thread[{1997, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
{1997, #} & /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Tuples[{{1997}, list}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> ```
> 1.6000000
> 0.8470000
> 0.1960000
> ```

Other methods just for  completeness:

```
Inner[List, Table[1997, {Length @ data1}], data1, List]

Outer[List, {1997}, data1] // Flatten[#, 1] &

Transpose@{Table[1997, {Length @ data1}], data1}
```

Comment: Apparently, we have a winner in `Tuples`. I've never used the second form, so I don't think of it. You already had my +1, but I'd give you another for that, if I could.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank You ! I knew there was a simple and fast method, however I couldn't find it and tried many strange ways until `Tuples`.

Comment: I understand about attempting to use [strange ways](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4654/52) to solve a [problem](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4571/52). The binary tree method, as written, is 4 times slower than any other method. Even with the speed ups! :)

Comment: I haven't read yet carefully those "strange ways" but that seems interesting.

Comment: I highly recommend the method Leonid pointed to as it is compiled. The issue with Andy's requirements, though, is that they include $\pm\infty$ which cannot be compiled.

Comment: Nice work!  For your "other methods" `ConstantArray` will be an order of magnitude faster than `Table`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank You ! `ConstantArray` is a real improvement for "other methods", but since it is entangled with `Transpose` or `Inner`, there we get only roughly 10-15 % of speed-up with respect to `Table`.

Answer (score 14):

The following works and is the way I would recommend:

```
{1997,#}&/@ data1
```

There is no need to create a list of 1997s of the same length as your original data.

I can think of a few other ways but they are more roundabout.

This version uses the optional third argument of `Riffle`.

```
Partition[Riffle[data1, 1997, {1, 2 Length[data1] - 1, 2}], 2]
```

There is no point using `FoldList` if you aren't using the intermediate values of the lists in your calculations, but the following works if what you really want is something more complicated than just joining `1997`.

```
FoldList[{1997, #2} &, {1997, First[data1]}, Rest@data1]
```

Answer (score 7):

As always, there are several ways to skin the cat. Here's yet another one:

```
data1 /. x_Integer :> {1997, x}
```

Use `x_Real` or `x_?NumericQ` as necessary, if your list is not exactly made of integers as in the example.

Answer (score 5):

One more:

```
ArrayFlatten@{{1997, List /@ data1}}
```

Comment: +1 for an [oft-forgotten](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31330/121) function. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's a nice function to get some points. :) tks