# Thread over list in different levels

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, code-review

I have these two lists, both with the same length in the first dimension:

```
l1={{a1,a2},{b1,b2},{c1,c2}};
l2={{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}},{{10,11,12},{13,14,15},{16,17,18}},{{19,20,21}}};
```

And I need mix both to get into this result:

```
{{a1,a2,1,2,3},{a1,a2,4,5,6},{b1,b2,10,11,12},{b1,b2,13,14,15},
{b1,b2,16,17,18},{c1,c2,19,20,21}}
```

I have done this code that do the job:

```
Flatten[MapThread[Function[{a,b},Join[a,#]&/@b][#1,#2]&,{l1,l2}],1]
```

But I think it could be simpler. Some clue?

Comment: Short and fast is always the best.

Comment: A lot of people don't bother to look at answers to old questions; I appreciate the fact that you do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why no one thought to use [`ArrayFlatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html):

```
wizard1[l1_, l2_] := ArrayFlatten @ MapThread[Append, {l1, l2}]

wizard2[l1_, l2_] := ArrayFlatten @ Join[l1, List /@ l2, 2]
```

Test:

```
wizard1[l1, l2]

wizard1[l1, l2] === wizard2[l1, l2]
```

> ```
>  {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12},
>   {b1, b2, 13, 14, 15}, {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}}
>
> True
> ```

According to ssch's test suite these functions are also the fastest:

```
testSpeed[50000, 15]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

A similar alternative

```
MapThread[Flatten /@ Tuples[{{#1}, #2}] &, {l1, l2}]~Flatten~1
```

> {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12}, {b1, b2, 
>     13, 14, 15}, {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}}

Comment: Nice! I liked the way you use Tuples to distribute the elements.

Comment: I little bit faster with `Flatten[MapThread[Tuples[{{#1},#2}]&,{l1,l2}],{{1,2},{3,4}}]`

Answer (score 9):

Something a bit compact:

```
Flatten[MapThread[Join[ConstantArray[#1, Length[#2]], #2, 2] &, {l1, l2}], 1]
(* {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12}, {b1, b2, 13, 14, 15},
    {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}} *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Using combinations of `Thread` and `Join`:

```
Join @@@ Join @@ (Thread[#, List, {2}] & /@ Thread@{l1, l2})
```

or (... why not?)

```
Join @@@ Join @@ (Thread[{##}, List, {2}] & @@@ Thread@{l1, l2})
```

UPDATE: ... few more:

Using `ArrayPad`:

```
Join@@(ArrayPad[#[[1]], {{0}, {2, 0}}, #[[2]]] & /@ Thread[{l2,Reverse/@ l1}])
```

and variations with `MapThread`:

```
Join @@ MapThread[ArrayPad[#1, {{0}, {2, 0}}, #2] &, {l2, Reverse /@ l1}]

Join @@ MapThread[Function[{a, b}, Join[a, #] & /@ b], {l1, l2}]

Join @@ MapThread[Function[e, Join[#1, e]] /@ #2 &, {l1, l2}]
```

Comment: I was about to give it a try when I noticed that your answer's better than mine in every single way.

Comment: @VF1, thank you... you might like the updated version with 9 `@`s :)

Comment: +1 Excellent idea with the `ArrayPad`.

Comment: @Sasha, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Your approach looks fine to me, but here's an alternative using `Outer` and `Thread`:

```
(Outer[Flatten[{##}] &, {#1}, #2, 1] & @@@ Thread[{l1, l2}]) ~Flatten~ 2
(* {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12}, {b1, b2, 13, 14, 15}, 
    {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}} *)
```

You could also use `Transpose[{l1,l2}]` instead of thread (`\[Transpose]` looks compact in the front end).

Answer (score 7):

One more with `Thread` and `Map`:

```
Flatten[Thread[f[l1, l2]] /. f[a_, b_] :> (Join[a, #] & /@ b), 1]
```

And one with `PadLeft`:

```
Flatten[MapThread[PadLeft[#1, {Length@#1, 5}, #2] &, {l2, Reverse /@ l1}], 1]
```

I wonder whether we can abuse `Partition`'s padding capabilities (or even `Riffle`'s)...

Answer (score 7):

You're joining columns at the 3rd level but have ragged lists:

```
DeleteCases[Flatten[Join[{#, #, #} &/@l1, l2, 3], 1], {_, _}]

(* {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12}, {b1, b2, 
  13, 14, 15}, {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}} *)
```

(Joining ragged lists gives you an non-ragged list with padding that has to be removed with `DeleteCases` otherwise this could be concise)

Answer (score 7):

I did some speed comparisons on the different solutions

```
murta[l1_, l2_] := 
  Flatten[MapThread[
    Function[{a, b}, Join[a, #] & /@ b][#1, #2] &, {l1, l2}], 1];
rojo[l1_, l2_] := 
  MapThread[Flatten /@ Tuples[{{#1}, #2}] &, {l1, l2}]~Flatten~1;
jm[l1_, l2_] := 
  Flatten[MapThread[
    Join[ConstantArray[#1, Length[#2]], #2, 2] &, {l1, l2}], 1];
rmrf[l1_, 
   l2_] := (Outer[Flatten[{##}] &, {#1}, #2, 1] & @@@ 
     Thread[{l1, l2}])~Flatten~2;
mike[l1_, l2_] := 
  DeleteCases[Flatten[Join[{#, #, #} & /@ l1, l2, 3], 1], {_, _}];
istván1[l1_, l2_] := 
  Flatten[Thread[f[l1, l2]] /. f[a_, b_] :> (Join[a, #] & /@ b), 1];
istván2[l1_, l2_] := 
  Flatten[MapThread[
    PadLeft[#1, {Length@#1, 5}, #2] &, {l2, Reverse /@ l1}], 1];
imagedr[l1_, l2_] := 
  Flatten[Thread[
      Join @@ {#[[1]], #[[2]]\[Transpose]}] & /@ ({l1, 
       l2}\[Transpose]), 1];
kguler1[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@@ Join @@ (Thread[#, List, {2}] & /@ Thread@{l1, l2});
kguler2[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@@ Join @@ (Thread[{##}, List, {2}] & @@@ Thread@{l1, l2});
kguler3[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@ (ArrayPad[#[[1]], {{0}, {2, 0}}, #[[2]]] & /@ 
     Thread[{l2, Reverse /@ l1}]);
kguler4[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@ MapThread[
    ArrayPad[#1, {{0}, {2, 0}}, #2] &, {l2, Reverse /@ l1}];
kguler5[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@ MapThread[Function[{a, b}, Join[a, #] & /@ b], {l1, l2}];
kguler6[l1_, l2_] := 
  Join @@ MapThread[Function[e, Join[#1, e]] /@ #2 &, {l1, l2}];

mthds = {murta, rojo, jm, rmrf, mike, istván1, istván2, imagedr, 
   kguler1, kguler2, kguler3, kguler4, kguler5, kguler6};
testSpeed[n_, m_] := Module[{l1, l2},
  l1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
  l2 = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {RandomInteger[{1, m}], 3}], {n}];
  Sort[Map[
     {ToString[#], First[AbsoluteTiming[#[l1, l2]]]} &, mthds], 
    Last[#1] < Last[#2] &] // TableForm
  ]
```

First test, both lists length 5000, second one has at most 5 lists to append:

```
testSpeed[5000, 5]
kguler4 0.035028
mike    0.040346
istván2 0.042375
jm  0.044726
kguler3 0.044926
istván1 0.054379
kguler5 0.059240
kguler1 0.060311
kguler2 0.062870
murta   0.065296
kguler6 0.065683
imagedr 0.080554
rmrf    0.102988
rojo    0.116306
```

With up to 50 sublists:

```
testSpeed[5000, 50]
kguler4 0.051828
kguler3 0.059161
jm  0.100330
istván2 0.102177
imagedr 0.139533
mike    0.188815
istván1 0.268590
kguler5 0.270507
murta   0.285236
kguler6 0.343441
kguler2 0.365733
kguler1 0.367342
rojo    0.595591
rmrf    0.684573
```

So I'd go with kgulers solution:

```
Join @@ MapThread[
    ArrayPad[#1, {{0}, {2, 0}}, #2] &, {l2, Reverse /@ l1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

A variant using `Thread` and `Transpose`

```
Flatten[Thread[Join @@ {#[[1]], #[[2]]\[Transpose]}] & /@ ({l1, l2}\[Transpose]),1]
```

> {{a1, a2, 1, 2, 3}, {a1, a2, 4, 5, 6}, {b1, b2, 10, 11, 12}, {b1, b2, 
>     13, 14, 15}, {b1, b2, 16, 17, 18}, {c1, c2, 19, 20, 21}}