# How can I merge two lists in a special way?

Tags: list-manipulation

It's been over a year since I've used Mathematica, and I'm having a total brain fart on a home project.  I'd like to take an existing list of lists, say,

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}
```

and append 9 and 10 onto the end of each sublist of x to get a list y, where

```
y = {{1, 2, 9}, {1 ,2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}
```

I'm sure there's a built-in function to do this, but cannot recall it for the life of me.

Comment: Closely related: [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
y = {9, 10};
Flatten /@ Tuples[{x, y}]
(*
{{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}
*)
```

Comment: Tuples.  That was the function I had forgotten.

Answer (score 9):

```
Flatten /@ Distribute[{x, {9, 10}}, List]
```

=> {1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility using `Outer`:

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
y = {9, 10};
Outer[# ~Join~ {#2} &, x, y, 1]
```

or

```
Outer[Flatten @ {##} &, x, y, 1]
```

Flatten the above result at level 1, if you want an output like in belisarius' answer.

Comment: +1. You could have used `Outer[Append, x, y, 1]` instead.

Comment: @Leonid It's a little trick I learned... people have an irrational dislike of `Append` ("eeek! don't use `AppendTo` to grow a list", etc.), but not `Join`, although they both do the same thing (and are equally "problematic").  So the less one uses it in an answer, the better the chances of an upvote =) "Irrational" was probably the wrong word, because it is completely justified, but what I really mean is that the dislike is attached to the _word_ rather than to what it does (or how). Of course, a +1 comment from you increases the chances of trickle down upvotes much more, so it's a net win :D

Answer (score 7):

Some I wrote before reading other answers, from shortest to longest:

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};

Append @@@ Tuples @ {x, {9, 10}}

Join @@ Outer[Append, x, {9, 10}, 1]

Flatten[{{##, 9}, {##, 10}} & @@@ x, 1]

Join @@ Thread /@ ArrayFlatten@{{x, {9, 10}}}

Join @@ Table[a ~Append~ b, {a, x}, {b, {9, 10}}]
```

And I just thought of:

```
## &[{##, 9}, {##, 10}] & @@@ x
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**  ... forgot `Table`!!

```
 Join @@ Table[Flatten@{i, j}, {i, x}, {j, y}]
```

or, with the new-in-Version-9 `ArrayReshape`,

```
 ArrayReshape[Table[{i, j}, {i, x}, {j, y}], {6, 3}]
 (* {{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}} *)
```

---

```
Join @@ (PadRight[x, {1 + Length@First@x, Length@x}, #] & /@ y) // Sort
(* {{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}} *)
```

or

```
Distribute[Append[{x}, y], List, List, List, Append]
Distribute[{x, y}, List, List, List, Append]
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to be different:

```
MapIndexed[#1~Join~(10 - Mod[#2, 2]) &, Riffle[x, x]]
Join @@@ Riffle[Riffle[x, x], {{9}, {10}}, {2, -1, 2}]~Partition~2
(*{{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `Replace`:**

```
x = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

Replace[x, {a_, b_} :> Sequence[{a, b, 9}, {a, b, 10}], {1}]
```

> {{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}

Answer (score 4):

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
Join @@ SequenceReplace[x, {x_} :> {Join[x, {9}], Join[x, {10}]}]

(*{{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}*)
```

The following equivalent form is courtesy of @Syed:

```
SequenceReplace[x, {x_} :> Sequence[{Sequence @@ x, 9}, {Sequence @@ x, 10}]]

(*{{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}*)
```

Comment: `SequenceReplace[x, {x_} :> 
  Sequence[{Sequence @@ x, 9}, {Sequence @@ x, 10}]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
flank[a_][b_] := Splice @ Map[Append[b, #] &, a]

flank[{9, 10}] /@ x
```

{{1, 2, 9}, {1, 2, 10}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 4, 10}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 6, 10}}

```
flank[{p, q}] /@ x
```

{{1, 2, p}, {1, 2, q}, {3, 4, p}, {3, 4, q}, {5, 6, p}, {5, 6, q}}