# given n lists, get list of applications of function to n-tuples

Tags: replacement, functional-style

Is there a built in function or an easy rule to do the following transformation?

```
H[{A[0], A[1], ...},{B[0], B[1], ...},...]
```

into

```
{H[A[0], B[0]], H[A[1], B[1]], ...}
```

Comment: `Thread` might help you.

Comment: and what happened to `A[0]` and `B[0]`?

Comment: @Spawn1701D ok `Thread` does it, thanks. @PinguinDirk, corrected.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thread` does this:

```
expr = h[{a[0], a[1], a[2]}, {b[0], b[1], b[2]}, {c[0], c[1], c[2]}];

Thread[expr]
```

> ```
> {h[a[0], b[0], c[0]], h[a[1], b[1], c[1]], h[a[2], b[2], c[2]]}
> ```

If however your subexpressions are not the same length you will get an error:

```
expr2 = h[{a[0], a[1], a[2]}, {b[0], b[1]}, {c[0]}];

Thread[expr2]
```

> Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in h[{a[0],a[1],a[2]},{b[0],b[1]},{c[0]}] cannot be combined. >>

One could use `Flatten` to do something like this:

```
h @@@ Flatten[List @@ expr2, {2}]
```

> ```
> {h[a[0], b[0], c[0]], h[a[1], b[1]], h[a[2]]}
> ```

To understand `Flatten` see: [Flatten command: matrix as second argument](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119/121).

There is a problem with the simple form above however.  Note what happens if `h` is made to hold its arguments unevaluated, and `a` is given a definition which we do not wish to trigger:

```
Attributes[h] = {HoldAll};

a[_] = "Fail!";
```

`Thread` still works as desired:

```
Thread[expr]
```

> ```
> {h[a[0], b[0], c[0]], h[a[1], b[1], c[1]], h[a[2], b[2], c[2]]}
> ```

The form with `Flatten` does not:

```
h @@@ Flatten[List @@ expr2, {2}]
```

> ```
> {h["Fail!", b[0], c[0]], h["Fail!", b[1]], h["Fail!"]}
> ```

We can get around that with:

```
List @@ Flatten[h @@@ expr2, {2}, h]
```

> ```
> {h[a[0], b[0], c[0]], h[a[1], b[1]], h[a[2]]}
> ```

Which could be generalized as:

```
raggedThread[x : h1_[h2_[___] ..]] := h2 @@ Flatten[h1 @@@ x, {2}, h1]

raggedThread[expr2]
```

> ```
> {h[a[0], b[0], c[0]], h[a[1], b[1]], h[a[2]]}
> ```