# appending element to sub list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of the form:

```
lstA = { 
         { {"a","b"}, -1.5}, 
         { {"c","d"}, -2  }   
       }
```

I wanto to add another value to each sublist that comes from another list

```
lstB = {-5,-10}
```

I would like the final list to look like

```
 mergeList =  { 
            { {"a","b"}, -1.5, -5 }, 
            { {"c","d"}, -2,-10 }
            }
```

I have tried using Append to get each sublist, and then append the value corresponding value from lstB:

```
  Append[{#1, #2} & @@@ lstA, lstB]
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Insert` or do you need `Append`?

Comment: I have been trying Append.  Append should work because I want to get each sublist then append the value from lstB

Comment: Very closely related: [(13748)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most efficient approach uses (new in *ver.6*) [**ArrayFlatten**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayFlatten.html?q=ArrayFlatten&lang=en):

```
ArrayFlatten[{{lstA, Transpose[{lstB}]}}]
```

> ```
> {{{"a", "b"}, -1.5, -5}, {{"c", "d"}, -2, -10}}
> ```

Instead of threading `Append` which is not very efficient, another much faster way  would use also `Transpose` twice and `Append` only once:

```
Transpose @ Append[ Transpose @ lstA, lstB]
```

or alternatively one could exploit the second argument of `Join` using `Transpose` only once:

```
Join[ lstA, Transpose[{lstB}], 2]
```

In the *Front-end* `Transpose` can be is rewritten (using `Esc+ tr + Esc`) in especially terse (neat) way, e.g.:

[image]

Moreover we have:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can do that using [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html):

```
mergeList = MapThread[Append, {lstA, lstB}]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since I like to stick with my ideas, here is an example with `Insert`:

```
Insert[lstA[[#1]], #2, #3] & @@@ Thread[{Range@Length@lstA, lstB, {3, 3}}]
```

> ```
> {{{"a", "b"}, -1.5, -5}, {{"c", "d"}, -2, -10}}
> ```