# Filter sublists that contain a certain value

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

This question is a followup from  [appending elements to sublist](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47019/appending-element-to-sub-list)

```
mergedList =     { 
        { {"a","b"}, -1.5, -5, "no" }, 
        { {"c","d"}, -2,-10, 7 }

}
```

I have processed my data, and I want to remove every sublist that contains "no".  I tried

```
DeleteCases[mergedList, "no", 2]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: It works, but indeed, not the way you want. You have to specify what to delete with pattern: `DeleteCases[mergedList, {__, "no"}]`

Comment: I'd say it's a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45429/5478 the only difference is that there is `Cases`.