# How to insert elements of a list into list of lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists. E.g.

```
l1 = {{{t1, d11}, {t2, d12}, {t3, d13}}, 
      {{t1, d21}, {t2, d22}, {t3, d23}}, 
      {{t1, d31}, {t2, d32}, {t3, d33}}, 
      {{t1, d41}, {t2, d42}, {t3, d43}}};

l2 = {p1, p2, p3, p4};
```

I would like to generate a list like res.

```
l22 = Table[l2[[i]], {i, 1, Length[l2]}, {Length[l1]}];

res = Table[Riffle[l1[[i, j]], l22[[i]], 3], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{{t1, d11, p1}, {t2, d12, p1}, {t3, d13, p1}}, 
> {{t1, d21, p2}, {t2, d22, p2}, {t3, d23, p2}},
> {{t1, d31, p3}, {t2, d32, p3}, {t3, d33, p3}},
> {{t1, d41, p4}, {t2, d42, p4}, {t3, d43, p4}}}
> ```

It would be nice to have a code in one step and without counting the length of the list.
I have seen similar manipulations with `Append` or `Join`, but I could not combined with mapping to get the right structure.

Comment: related: [13748](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13748/5478)

Comment: [cross posted on Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/487950?p_p_auth=E2ptF7CJ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I feel like it is a duplicate, but I can't find it, so here's one way:

```
MapThread[Flatten /@ Thread[{##}] &, {l1, l2}]
```

or another:

```
MapThread[# /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, #2} &, {l1, l2}]
```

> ```
> {{{t1, d11, p1}, {t2, d12, p1}, {t3, d13, p1}}, 
> {{t1, d21, p2}, {t2, d22, p2}, {t3, d23, p2}}, 
> {{t1, d31, p3}, {t2, d32, p3}, {t3, d33, p3}}, 
> {{t1, d41, p4}, {t2, d42, p4}, {t3, d43, p4}}}
> ```

And ugly one:

```
Riffle[Transpose[Flatten /@ l1], {l2}, {3, -1, 3}]//Transpose//ArrayReshape[#, {4, 3, 3}] &
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Flatten /@ Thread[#] & /@ Transpose[{l1, l2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[Map[Function[pair, Append[pair, #2]], #1] &, {l1, l2}]
```