# Adding elements of second list in succession

Tags: list-manipulation

Given

```
 t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
 t2 = {{a, b, c}, {e, f}};
```

I want to add in succession elements of list 2 to list 1 to get:

```
{{1, 2, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 2, c}, {3, 4, e}, {3, 4, f}}
```

I can do it by:

```
Flatten[MapThread[Flatten /@ Tuples[{{#1}, #2}] &, {t1, t2}], 1]
```

as indicated in [Thread over list in different levels](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13748/thread-over-list-in-different-levels). This is pretty rough. Any ideas how to do it in a reasonable concise way and easier to understand?

Answer (score 9):

Your method is quite concise.

You can also do:

```
MapThread[## & @@ Thread[{## & @@ #, #2}] &]@{t1, t2}

Join @@ MapThread[Thread[{## & @@ #, #2}] &] @ {t1, t2}

Join @@ MapThread[Flatten /@ Thread[{##}, List, {2}] &] @ {t1, t2}

Join @@ MapThread[Function[{a, b}, Append[a, #] & /@ b]] @ {t1, t2}

Join @@ Map[Flatten]@*Tuples /@ Thread[{List /@ t1, t2}]
```

to get

> ```
> {{1, 2, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 2, c}, {3, 4, e}, {3, 4, f}}
> ```

And a Halloween special:

[image]

```
☺ = {## & @@ #, #2} /. 
      {♯__, ♯♯ : {__}} :>
       (## & @@ ({♯, #} & /@ ♯♯)) & @@@
    ({##}\[Transpose]) &;

☺[t1, t2]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, a}, {1, 2, b}, {1, 2, c}, {3, 4, e}, {3, 4, f}}
> ```

Comment: First I thought your last solution is a joke! But it really works! I am still struggling to understand your other solutions but concerning this last one, I think I will come back to you X-mas next year!

Comment: ## & @@@ t1  is equivalent to Flatten[t1]. What is then the equivalent of Flatten[{t1,t2}]?

Comment: @user57467, `Apply[## &, {t1, t2}, 2]`?

Comment: @kgIr, I tried hard to analyze your code, but in `Thread[{## & @@ #, #2}] &` I can't figure out what ##,#, and #2 refer to.Can you explain, please! Sorry for asking dumb questions.

Comment: @user57467, `foo = Thread[{## & @@ #, #2}] & ` is a _pure_ function ( a function with _unnamed_ arguments) that does the same thing as the function `bar[x_,y_] := Thread[{Apply[Sequence][x],y}]`. The function `##&` is  the function [Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sequence.html),  andt he form `buz@@x` is the same as `Apply[buz][x]`  (see  [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)). The symbols `#` ([Slot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) ), `#2`,`#3,...represent the _first_, _second_,_third_,... arguments supplied to a function.

Comment: ... To see the reason for using `Apply[Sequence]` on the first argument, let `x={2,4,5};y={u,v}; ` and try `Thread[{Apply[Sequence][x],y}]` vs `Thread[{x,y}]`.

Comment: ... and see [this flash animation](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Thread.html) on how `Thread` works on a list of lists.

Answer (score 6):

Given:

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{a, b, c}, {e, f}};
```

`ReplacePart` can express the transformation reasonably directly:

```
ReplacePart[t2, {i_,j_} :> Append[t1[[i]], t2[[i,j]]]] // Catenate


(* {{1,2,a},{1,2,b},{1,2,c},{3,4,e},{3,4,f}} *)
```

The same technique is textually shorter using `MapIndexed`, but perhaps a little less readable:

```
MapIndexed[Append[t1[[#2[[1]]]], #] &, t2, {2}] // Catenate

(* {{1,2,a},{1,2,b},{1,2,c},{3,4,e},{3,4,f}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

I also use `Outer` to construct the list.

```
t1 = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
t2 = {{a, b, c}, {e, f}};
MapThread[
  Outer[Flatten@*List, {#1}, #2, 1]~Flatten~1 &, {t1, t2}]~Flatten~1
Flatten /@ MapThread[Outer[List, {#1}, #2, 1] &, {t1, t2}]~Flatten~2
```

Answer (score 4):

Or using `CartesianProduct` from Combinatorica package

```
t1 = {{1,2},{3,4}};
t2 = {{a,b,c},{e,f}};

Needs["Combinatorica`"]
  
Flatten /@ Catenate @ MapThread[CartesianProduct,{List[#]& /@ t1,t2}]
```