# Combining two lists of different dimensions into a list of all combinations of points?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two ranges of values, one from `0` to `20` and the other from `0` to `80`.  I want to combine these into a list of "all possible" `{x, y}` coordinates that I can then plot later on.  So the final list of points would be `~1700` long, consisting of:

```
{{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2},..., {0,80}, {1,0}, {1,2}, {1,3},..., {1,80}, {2,0},..., {20, 80}}
```

I've seen things like `Riffle` and `Partition` thrown around but they're not quite what I'm looking for I think.

Comment: This is the Cartesian or outer product.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best aproach uses `Tuples` :

```
Tuples[{Range[0, 80], Range[0, 20]}] // Short
```

> ```
> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, <<1693>>, {80, 17}, {80, 18}, {80, 19}, {80, 20}}
> ```

or a bit more briefly :

```
Tuples[ Range @@@ {{0, 80}, {0, 20}}]
```

`Array` provides a different way :

```
Sequence @@@ Array[{#1, #2} &, {81, 21}, 0]
```

Comment: Haha, I seriously just figured it the second before I hit refresh to see if there were any responses before I deleted this. And that's exactly what I typed!  Thanks anyway. :P

Comment: @SixtySuit Oh, really ?  Take this comparison into account : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list/4751#4751

Comment: One can simplify the last method a little: `Sequence @@@ Array[ List , {81, 21}, 0]`

Answer (score 7):

A more general function is `Outer`

```
 tuples = Outer[ List, Range[0, 80], Range[0, 20]]
```

Depending on how you want to use it you might want to `Flatten` the output

```
 Flatten[ tuples, 1]
```

Answer (score 7):

Shorter versions of Artes' methods:

```
Tuples @ Range[0, {80, 20}]

Join @@ Array[List, {81, 21}, 0]
```

Related methods that may be of use:

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {q, r, s};

Distribute[{a, b}, List]
```

> ```
> {{1, q}, {1, r}, {1, s}, {2, q}, {2, r}, {2, s}, {3, q},
>  {3, r}, {3, s}, {4, q}, {4, r}, {4, s}}
> ```

```
Inner[f, List /@ a, {b}, g]
```

> ```
> {{g[f[1, q]], g[f[1, r]], g[f[1, s]]}, {g[f[2, q]], g[f[2, r]], 
>   g[f[2, s]]}, {g[f[3, q]], g[f[3, r]], g[f[3, s]]}, {g[f[4, q]], 
>   g[f[4, r]], g[f[4, s]]}}
> ```

```
Outer[f, a, b]
```

> ```
> {{f[1, q], f[1, r], f[1, s]}, {f[2, q], f[2, r], f[2, s]}, {f[3, q], 
>   f[3, r], f[3, s]}, {f[4, q], f[4, r], f[4, s]}}
> ```

Notice the different levels preserved and opportunities to apply custom functions in each case.  All methods shown have a place.

Also be familiar with the syntax of `Table` which is closely related to `Do`, `Sum`, `Product`, etc.

```
Table[{i, j}, {i, a}, {j, b}]
```

> ```
> {{{1, q}, {1, r}, {1, s}}, {{2, q}, {2, r}, {2, s}}, {{3, q},
>   {3, r}, {3, s}}, {{4, q}, {4, r}, {4, s}}}
> ```

```
Product[i + j, {i, a}, {j, b}]
```

> ```
> (1 + q) (2 + q) (3 + q) (4 + q) (1 + r) (2 + r) (3 + r) (4 + r) (1 + s) (2 + s) (3 + s) (4 + s)
> ```

Also related is:

```
KroneckerProduct[a, b]
```

> ```
> {{q, r, s}, {2 q, 2 r, 2 s}, {3 q, 3 r, 3 s}, {4 q, 4 r, 4 s}}
> ```