# Threading a single abscissa through a list of ordinates

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose that I have the following list, called `list`.  `list` contains elements `X`, `X1`, `X2`, and `X3`:

```
list = {X, {X1, X2, X3}}
```

I would like a function that operates on `list` and gives the following output list:

```
{{X, X1}, {X, X2}, {X, X3}}
```

Is there a simple way to accomplish this with `Thread`, `MapThread`, `Inner`, `Through`, or the like?  I feel like this should be simple, but I am having a lot of trouble coming up with a simple solution.

So far, I have only been able to come up with rather complicated solutions, such as

```
Transpose[{Table[#[[1]], {Length[#[[2]]]}], #[[2]]}] &@list
```

> {{X, X1}, {X, X2}, {X, X3}}

Comment: Thread[{X,{X1,X2,X3}}]

Comment: I recommed `Tuples`: `Tuples[{{X}, {X1, X2, X3}}]`, for another solutions and benchmarks see this [post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list/4751#4751).