# How to append to a list of lists elegantly

Tags: list-manipulation

I have have list of lists and I would like to be able to append an element to the start of each list. I am sure there must be an elegant solution.

EG: `a` and `{{b,c},{d,e,f}}` -> `{{a,b,c},{a,d,e,f}}`

If I want to apply a function to a list of lists I normally use `@@@` however I don't know how to modify this so that it gets feed into the second argument or `AppendTo`.

Can someone please explain how I could achieve this?

Comment: `Prepend[#, a] & /@ {{b, c}, {d, e, f}}`? I feel there is a thread on this around already, probably with a thousand nice solutions...

Comment: Yep, thanks. I am bad with # and &. Cheers!

Comment: This is closely related [Interlacing a single number into a long list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list), however I'm sure there are exact duplicates of this question.

Comment: You're probably right, I had a search but did not find it, which probably says more about my searching skills.

Comment: I have marked this as "already has an answer" -- please see the link inserted at the top of the Question.  Although the examples there show a rectangular array many of the methods work on a ragged array as well.  Examples:  `Prepend[#, 0]& /@ lists` and `{0, ##} & @@@ lists`

Comment: Related: [(189)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be done with:

```
l = {{b, c}, {d, e, f}};
Join[{a}, #] & /@ l
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {a, d, e, f}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
{a, ##} & @@@ {{b, c}, {d, e, f}}
(* {{a, b, c}, {a, d, e, f}}  *)
```