# How to find all binary numbers with the kth =0 and smaller than 2^n?

Tags: programming, binary

I have been stuck in this problem for a long time.

I need to find a general code to collect all binary numbers which are at most n digits (`<2^(n-1)`) with the kth digit equal to 0. For example, I need to find all binary numbers in the form of x0xx (4 digits with the second one equal to 0), then I need to write three `For` loops and get the answer: `{0000,0001,0010,0011,1000,1001,1010,1011}`. However, if I change the value of n or k, I need to modify my code, so now I am trying to find a general code for any n and k.

My idea is

```
ithzero = Compile[{{k, _Integer},{n,_Integer}}, nul = {};Do[nul = Append[nul, BaseForm[i, 2]*Boole[IntegerDigits[i, 2, n][[k]] == 0]], {i, 0, 2^n - 1}]];
```

However, I am not satisfied with this code, because it gives many 0s due to `Boole`. By the way, I still don't have any idea about how to verify if x is in ithzero[n,k]. I thought `5\[Element]ithzero[5,2]` is a logic expression, but it isn't.

I am very grateful to any help!

Comment: `ToString  /@  Row  /@  Select[Tuples[{0, 1}, n /. n -> 4], (#[[k /. k -> 2]] == 0) &]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html).  For example:

```
fn[n_, k_] /; 0 < k <= n :=
  Tuples @ ReplacePart[Table[{0, 1}, {n}], k -> {0}]

FromDigits[fn[4, 2]\[Transpose]]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 10, 11, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011}
> ```

Or as strings:

```
ToString /@ Row /@ fn[4, 2]
```

> ```
> {"0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011"}
> ```

Comment: Nice work, Thanks!

Comment: By the way, is there a neat way to convert {0, 1, 10, 11, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011} into decimal numbers?

Comment: @JieyuYou Certainly, just specify the correct base in `FromDigits`:  `FromDigits[fn[4, 2]\[Transpose], 2]` gives `{0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11}`

Answer (score 4):

Could use bit operations:

```
f[n_, k_] := Union @ BitAnd[Range[0,2^n-1], BitXor[2^n-1, 2^k]]

f[4, 2]
IntegerDigits[f[4, 2], 2, 4]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
>     0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}

Another faster possibility:

```
g[n_, k_] := Flatten @ Outer[Plus, 2^(k+1) Range[0, 2^(n-k-1)-1], Range[0, 2^k-1]]

g[4, 2]
IntegerDigits[g[4, 2], 2, 4]
```

> {0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 11}
>
> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
>     0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}

Comment: Fortunately, `BitClear[]` is now built-in: `Union[BitClear[Range[0, 2^n - 1], k]]`

Answer (score 0):

```
f1[n_, k_] := Insert[#, 0, k] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, n - 1]
f1[4, 2]
(*{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0},
{1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}}*)
```

Instead of mapping each element and inserting `0`, we can transpose the list and use `Insert[]` to insert a `ConstantArray`.

```
f2[n_, k_] := Insert[#, ConstantArray[0, 2^(n - 1)], k] &@ 
Transpose@Tuples[{0, 1}, n - 1] // Transpose

f1[20,3]//AbsoluteTiming
f2[20,3]//AbsoluteTiming
fn[20,3]//AbsoluteTiming (*Mr.Wizard's solution*)
```

> 0.21
>
> 0.14
>
> 0.02

Comment: `Insert` while clear is orders of magnitude slower than using `Tuples` alone, and uses far more memory.  I encourage you compare the two.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, you are right. I checked it and it is almost an order of magnitude slower compared to yours. I don't seem to understand the purpose of `insert` at all if it can't be applied even for a question like this. It might be because of mapping the list. I tried to use `Insert`in a different way, but it is still slower than yours, please check the edit. Can I include the timing of your solution for the purpose of comparison?

Comment: Of course you may include timings for my function if you wish.  `Insert` is very useful it just isn't particularly fast as it must be applied once for each element.  It is almost always faster to perform vectorized operations in *Mathematica*, apart from compilation.  See e.g. [(7996)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7996/121) for some possibly useful examples.

Comment: Also `Tuples` is especially fast (see [(4751)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4751/121)) so it is best for performance to use it directly rather than further processing its output, where possible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is updated.

In:

```
Clear[f]
f[n_, k_] := Module[{xss},
  xss = Tuples[{0, 1}, n];
  xss [[All, k]] = 0 xss [[All, k]] ;
  Union[xss]]
 f[5, 1]
```

Out:

```
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 
  1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1, 
  1}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 
  1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 
  1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where k is position from right:

```
f[n_, k_] := 
 Flatten[IntegerDigits[2^k # + Range[0, 2^(k - 1) - 1], 2, n] & /@ 
   Range[0, 2^(n - k) - 1], 1]
Row@(ArrayPlot[f[6, #], PlotLabel -> Row[{"k=", #}], 
     ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Range[6])
```

[image]

Where k is position from left:

```
g[n_, k_] := f[n, n - k + 1]
Row@(ArrayPlot[g[6, #], PlotLabel -> Row[{"kl=", #}], 
     ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Range[6])
```

[image]