# Generate a list of points based on the y coordinate

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of numbers corresponding to the known ordinates of some points:

```
x = {60, 101, 61, 203, 248, 346, 464,
     635, 635, 958, 1019, 1020, 1182, 
     1276, 1397, 1607, 1710, 1869, 1975}
```

How can I generate a new list of points based on that one by adding an index, such as

```
P = {{1, 60}, {2, 101}, {3, 61}, ....}
```

Comment: `{Range[Length@x], x}\[Transpose]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is most likely the most efficient approach:

```
Transpose[{Range[Length[x]], x}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 60}, {2, 101}, {3, 61}, {4, 203}, {5, 248}, {6, 346}, {7, 464}, {8, 635}, 
>   {9, 635}, {10, 958}, {11, 1019}, {12, 1020}, {13, 1182}, {14, 1276}, {15, 1397}, 
>   {16, 1607}, {17, 1710}, {18, 1869}, {19, 1975}}
> ```

Another approach (less efficient), that one could mention:

```
MapIndexed[ Flatten @ {#2, #1} &, x]
```

In a more general case instead of a strictly homogeneous distribution of the domain points we might deal with a random distribution which is still globally homogeneous, e.g.

```
y = RandomReal[{-1/2, 1/2}, #] + Range[#] & @ Length[x]
```

> ```
> { 1.01273, 1.6359, 3.38264, 4.08369, 5.05749, 6.12815, 7.35125, 7.93196, 
>   8.97418, 10.2015, 10.824, 12.0907, 13.2303, 14.3775, 15.2711, 16.3996,
>  17.3865, 17.7342, 19.4849}
> ```

and then we generate the list simply with:

```
Transpose[{y, x}]
```

Comment: How to load the abscissa from another list?

Comment: There is no abscissa, you have to generate it with `Range`, yielding `{1,2, ..., 19}`

Comment: @Mertin You can get it with `MapIndexed` as well as I demonstrated in the post.

Comment: Also, `Thread[{Range[Length[x]], x}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon,  Good point, thanks! Although `Transpose` should be much faster than `Thread`, see e.g. [Interlacing a single number into a long list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4748/interlacing-a-single-number-into-a-long-list/4751#4751) where it is compared with `Map` and `Tuples`.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to have an easy solution:

```
ResourceFunction["AddIndices"][x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
P=Table[{k,x[[k]]},{k,1,Length[x]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

For variety:

```
TimeSeries[x, {1}]["Path"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 60}, {2, 101}, {3, 61}, {4, 203}, {5, 248}, {6, 346}, {7, 464}, 
>  {8, 635}, {9, 635}, {10, 958}, {11, 1019}, {12, 1020}, {13, 1182}, 
>  {14, 1276}, {15, 1397}, {16, 1607}, {17, 1710}, {18, 1869}, {19, 1975}}
> ```

```
TemporalData[x, {1}]["Path"]
```

> ```
> {{1, 60}, {2, 101}, {3, 61}, {4, 203}, {5, 248}, {6, 346}, {7, 464}, 
>  {8, 635}, {9, 635}, {10, 958}, {11, 1019}, {12, 1020}, {13, 1182}, 
>  {14, 1276}, {15, 1397}, {16, 1607}, {17, 1710}, {18, 1869}, {19, 1975}}
> ```